# Первые шаги а написание кода, подскажите как зациклить калькулятор?

Tags: циклы

```
# Дебильный калькулятор V.2.0

from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

# use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
init()
print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.YELLOW )


what = input( "Selected action (+, -, *, **, %, /): " )
print( Back.GREEN )

a = float( input("Enter a first number: ") )
print( Back.CYAN )
b = float( input("Enter a second number: ") )

print( Back.MAGENTA )

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
elif what == "**":
    c = a ** b
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
elif what == "%":
    c = a % b 
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
elif what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print ("Result: " + str(c))
else:   
    print( Back.RED )
    print("Error 404")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Бесконечный цикл

   ```
   while True:
       код
   ```
2. Конечное число операций

   ```
   i = 0
   while i < 100:
       код
       i += 1
   ```

или

```
i = 0
iterations = 100
while i < iterations:
    код
    i += 1
```

или

```
for _ in range(iterations):
    код
```

3. путем ввода команды, завершающей цикл, например "stop"

   ```
   while True:
       what = input( "Selected action (+, -, *, **, %, /): " )
       if what == 'stop':
           break
       else:
           ваш код
   ```